# How can I force my app into the Applications/ folder?

Tags: objective-c, macos, hockeyapp

I am currently developing a desktop app in OS X which has a requirement for Autostart on Boot. I have implemented autostart and it works well when I install my app and put it in the Applications/ folder, but I can't expect users to move the file. I am distributing the app using HockeyApp.

So I've started building .pkg files with Packages. This works great and was really easy, but fails to update when used in HockeyApp. After downloading the update, I get a message saying `An error occurred while trying to extract the archive. Please try again later. [Cancel Update]`

Things I have tried:

- Signing the update
- Not signing the update
- Downloading the most recent version instead of updating (works perfectly fine)
- Zipping the .pkg (Fails to upload to HockeyApp)

How can I force my app into the user's Applications/ folder? Should I just ask my handful of (technologically challenged) beta testers to delete their app and download the new version? Can I make a change to my .pkg method to make it work? Should I add code into the app which moves itself (Sounds hacky and painful)?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot force the user to install into `/Applications`, however if you get the app to arrange the auto-start itself (for example via the App Preferences) then it should use the current location of the app (probably obtained from `[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]`) and that will work fine.

You might want to periodically check if the app has moved after this has been turned-on.